# Regex capture group works in Javascript and regex101, but not in sed

Tags: javascript, regex, sed, capture-group

In regex101: https://regex101.com/r/FM88LA/1

[image]

In my browser console:

```js
x='"AbCd123|999"';
"\"AbCd123|999\""
x.match(/[^\""|]+/)
Array [ "AbCd123" ]
```

Using sed in the shell:

```sh
(base) balter@winmac:~/winhome/CancerGraph/TCGA$ echo '"AbCd123|99999"' | sed -En 's/([^\"|]+)/\1/p'
"AbCd123|99999"
(base) balter@winmac:~/winhome/CancerGraph/TCGA$ echo '"AbCd123|99999"' | sed -En 's/\"([^|]+)/\1/p'
AbCd123|99999"
```

Comment: What does this have to do with bash? You're using sed.

Comment: sed uses extended posix, it wont work with your standard pcre

Comment: You don't need to escape `"` in regular expressions.

Comment: What's the expected output? In the first command the capture group contains the entire match, so you're just replacing it with itself and the output is the same as the input.

Comment: In the second command, the capture group doesn't include the `"`, so it removes the `"`.

Comment: To answer the questions in order: 1) I just wasn't sure if bash had it's own version of sed, so just wanted to be clear. 2) In javascript it seemed like I needed to, so I figured it wouldn't hurt. 3) The expected output is what I got in javascript and what is  shown in the regex101 example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is all fine, because `sed` command used with `-n` option and `p` flag only prints the text that was not matched + the result of the successful replacement.

That means, you can get your "match" with

```sh
echo '"AbCd123|99999"' | sed -En 's/["|]*([^"|]+).*/\1/p'
```

See the  [online demo](https://ideone.com/gI0lJf).

Here, the pattern gets to the first char that is not `"` and `|` with `["|]*`, then the `([^"|]+)` part captures one or more chars other than `"` and `|`, and then `.*` matches the rest of the string.

Everything that was matched but not captured is removed as you only ask to `p`rint the `\1`, the Group 1 value (captured with `([^"|]+)`).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think I needed to match all the stuff outside the capture group. But that definitely did the trick.